# illegal string offset codeigniter 3

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i've been trying to show my array result to a table
but getting error like this ..
 Message: Illegal string offset 'id_kls'

the arrays shows like this

```
Array
(
    [error_code] => 0
    [error_desc] => 
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id_kls] => 0075ab85-cf84-4cb4-80d2-36cf721b75bc
                    [fk__id_kls] => 01
                    [id_reg_pd] => 005ffefb-2cd9-424a-8a96-937c95461e83
                    [nm_pd] => RIDWAN PRIHANTORO
                    [asal_data] => 9
                    [nilai_angka] => 
                    [nilai_huruf] => B  
                    [nilai_indeks] => 3.00
                )
```

and go on ..
.
here my code, all code still on controller only ..

```
$tampan = $proxy->GetRecordset($token, $table, $filter, $order, $limit, $offset);
$hasil = $tampan;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tampan); 
echo '</pre>';
$data = $tampan;
?>
<table border="1">

    <tr>
    <th>No.</th>
        <th>id_kls</th>
        <th>fk__id_kls</th>
        <th>id_reg_pd</th>
        <th>nm_pd</th>
        <th>asal_data</th>
        <th>nilai_angka</th>
        <th>nilai_huruf</th>
        <th>nilai_index</th>
        </tr>

    <?php $no=1;  foreach($data as $key) { ?> <!-- Mulai loop -->

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key['id_kls']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['fk__id_kls']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['id_reg_pd']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['nm_pd']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['asal_data']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['nilai_angka']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['nilai_huruf']; ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $key['nilai_indeks']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php  } ?> <!-- Selesai loop -->

</table>
<?php

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Use $data["result"] in foreach

Comment: still error, like this Message: Undefined index: response

Comment: it fixed :) .. thanks for your help